# How to make optional assertions in regex?

Tags: regex

I have a sample string like this: `aibicidieif` (of more complicated string but similar format) and I tried a regex like `(?<=i).*?(?=i)` but it doesn't capture the first and last elements `a` and `f`.

I want everything in between the `i` delimiter but the regex only search for characters that have `i` before and after it.  Is there a way to make `(?=i)` and `(?<=i)` optional?

http://regexr.com?30mjf

Comment: @F.Müller: `(?<=i)?` means "it's preceded by `i`, or it isn't"; you might as well just remove the lookbehind (and the same goes for lookaheads).  Some regex flavors treat a quantified assertion as a syntax error--and those that don't, should.

Comment: Btw, the regex you provided __does__ capture the `f`

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think the `?` operator works on lookahead/behind anyway.

Comment: It seems I added an extra `i`.  I meant `aibicidieif`.

Comment: Optional lookahead/lookbehind can make sense if they contain capturing groups, for example `(?<=(a))?b` would match only the `b` in both `ab` and `cb`, but group 1 would contain `a` when matching `ab` and be empty when matching `cb`.  (However that doesn't apply to this question, and is very rarely useful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What language are you using?  In most languages you are able to split a string using a regex, for example in Python:

```
>>> re.split(r'i', 'aibicidieifi')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '']
```

Here `r'i'` could be replaced with a string representing whatever the more complicated regex is.

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
(?<=i|^).*?(?=i|$)
```

By adding anchors with alternation to the lookahead and lookbehind you will now still match characters at the start and end of strings, however some languages don't support variable length lookbehinds so this may not work.

If your language does not support variable length lookbehinds, here is an alternative that should still work:

```
(?:(?<=i)|^).*?(?=i|$)
```

Comment: Yes your regex is what I'm looking for.  I know there are functions available that do this but I was looking for a pure regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Won't simply `[^i]+` do the job?

Comment: In this case yes, but the OP did say it may be more complicated, so what is currently in the lookbehind and lookahead is probably not just a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input string and the delimiter are as straightforward as you are making them out to be, just do,

```
$valuesArray = explode('i', $input);
```

Then access the values from the created array.